# Cast for upcasting only

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming, upcasting

We all know that C-style casts are considered evil in C++. Which is why they are replaced by `const_cast<>`, `static_cast<>`, and `dynamic_cast<>` to provide for more bespoke casting, allowing the programmer to only allow the intended classes of conversions. So far, so good.

However, there seems to be no builtin syntax to perform an explicit upcast: A means to perform the otherwise implicit conversion in `Base& baseRef = derived` explicitly *without allowing the reverse*.

While I know that this is quite a small corner case (most of the time the implicit conversions work just fine), I was wondering what techniques are available to implement such a cast in user code. I was thinking about something along the lines of

```
template<class T>
class upcast {
    public:
        template<class U, typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_convertible<U, T>::value>::type>
        upcast(U value) : value(value) {}
        operator T() { return value; }
    private:
        T value;
};
```

However, that seems too complicated to be good, and since I'm not an expert in template-metaprogramming, I would like to ask whether there are different/better/simpler approaches.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve here. You can use static_cast to upcast.

Comment: You can't upcast `reference` with `dynamic_cast` or any other cast because `reference` can't be `null`, so there is no way to tell is upcast valid or not.

Comment: @LibertyPaul I'm not sure what you mean. Upcasting with `dynamic_cast` always succeeds and a bad downcast will throw `std::bad_cast` when using references.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve with disallowing implicit up casting?  Are you trying to stop object slicing?

Comment: I don't see where OP is asking to disallow up casting. They're asking for a construct in which this is valid `upcast<Base&>(my_derived);`, but this is not `upcast<Derived&>(my_base);`. i.e. they're wanting to disallow downcasting.

Comment: I want to *allow* upcasting, but *disallow* downcasting. `static_cast<>` allows both, which is bad because that allows for type mismatch errors. And whether you believe it or not, there are usecases, where `upcast<>` would come in handy (I would not have believed it myself yesterday ;-) ).

Comment: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/boost/implicit_cast.hpp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::forward<T&>` will only allow upcasts:

```
struct A {};
struct B : A {};
A a;
B b;
auto& x = std::forward<A&>(b); // OK
auto& y = std::forward<B&>(a); // fails
auto* px = std::forward<A*>(&b); // OK
auto* py = std::forward<B*>(&a); // fails
```